# Delay a javascript DOM style change

Tags: javascript, dom

this is my code:

```
document.addEventListener('mousedown', function (e) {
  bubbleDOM.style.visibility = 'hidden';
}, false);
```

My problem is that mousedown occurs on a link that i want to process, this link is
inside bubbleDOM. the hidden call is so quick that the link is not processed.

How do i delay `bubbleDOM.style.visibility = 'hidden'` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use setTimeout to delay your code

```
  setTimeout('your_code', time);
```

e.g:

```
  setTimeout('bubbleDOM.style.visibility = 'hidden';', 1000);
```

else,

instead of delaying the code, you can also redirect the user using javascript

```
  window.location = "http://www.google.com/";
```

Comment: setTimeout("bubbleDOM.style.visibility = 'hidden';", 100); worked thanks

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer is you can use setTimeout. [Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp) (may not be an elegant solution)

If you are waiting for some event to occur and then process, you can use callback for achieving it.

Answer (score 0):

Define `processing a link`. What exactly do you mean by 'the link is not processed'? Is the link supposed to be doing something? If it is, then the delay you require depends on the completion of whatever the link is supposed to do. You can set a timer using `setTimeout`, but it would be a very wrong practice.

Comment: proccess means going to that website aka "a href" and yes it's bad practice to use set time here so what do i do?

Comment: you can redirect the user from javascript itself when user clicks bubbleCom,use window.location to send the user to that link.See my answer.

Comment: Process that link in the onclick event of the link that is to be processed and not the parent element. This is due to possible conflicting event order mechanisms as implemented in various browsers: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html

Answer (score 0):

Use setTimeout

```
document.addEventListener('mousedown', function (e) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    bubbleDOM.style.visibility = 'hidden';
  }, 3000); // for 3 seconds
}, false);
```

Or you can use setInterval for loop check

```
document.addEventListener('mousedown', function (e) {
  var checkingInterval = setInterval(function() {
    // any ways to check if the bubbleDom is loaded?
    if (bubbleDOM != null) {
      bubbleDOM.style.visibility = 'hidden';
      // stop checking
      clearInterval(checkingInterval);
    }
  }, 3000); // for 3 seconds
}, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

setTimeout can delay the hide logic, but it may not work every time, because it depends on speed of browser, a short delay time may not trigger link click too

Why not use 'click' event?

```
document.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    bubbleDOM.style.visibility = 'hidden';
}, false);
```

Or you can do jump in listener function:

```
document.addEventListener('mousedown', function (e) {
    bubbleDOM.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    window.location = e.target.href;
}, false);
```